# simple javascript code doesn't work, can't figure out why

Tags: javascript

I don't use javascript alot but this should be so simple I shouldn't fail on it but after trying to get it working  for 30 minutes I need to ask for help:

I have this button

```
<button onclick="showMembers()">test</button>
```

and this code in the < head>

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function showMembers()
{
    document.getElementByID( 'MembersBox' ).style.display='block';

}
</script>
```

this is the html id:

```
<article id="MembersBox" style="display: none;" class="module width_quarter">
```

and I can't get it to show, nothing happens, inspecting it with firebug says nothing anywhere about javascript errors.

Comment: `getElementById` should have a lowercase "d". Are you sure there aren't any errors in the console?

Comment: wow! thank you. and no, I checked again setting it to ID and the "console" tab is completely empty.

Comment: [I get an error in firefox.](http://jsfiddle.net/u60g0mvd/9/)

Comment: I suggest trying it in another browser or using FireFox's built-in console. I too have had issues with stuff not showing up in the Firebug console.

Comment: Are you actually calling `showMembers`? You're not in your example.

Comment: @Andy OP's button has an inline event handler.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I missed that.

Comment: @Andy I'm using chrome with firebug lite, your link looks like this: http://i.gyazo.com/036f71f3b75c396b69ec950ada0768ce.png

Comment: You might want to switch to chrome dev tools instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `getElementByID` to `getElementById`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv7jjoqv/)

Comment: Why did someone downvote this?  It is a correct answer.